# cannot connect to sql server 2012 with java jdbc

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am learning `SQL/SQL Server 2012`. I am also learning how to make forms with java using `NetBeans`. I am trying to link java to my `SQL Server 2012 Express` so I can make a form that uses/updates data in a `SQL` database but have not been successful.

I have done lots of research trying to find a solution and made changes that I found I needed to make. I have set up `SQL Server` to use `TCP port 1433` on my computer. I have also made an exception in my firewall to allow that incoming connection. I have created a user "admin" and given that user sysadmin role. I have also set up `SQL Server` to allow remote connections with a time out of 60 seconds.

When I try to connect to the `SQL Server` from `MS SQL Server Management Studio` and put my computers static IP and port 1433, I get the attached error: 
[image: SQL error]

When I try to connect to the `SQL Server` database from `NetBeans` I get this:

> Cannot establish a connection to
>   jdbc:sqlserver://DEVINSPC\SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=Test using
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver (The TCP/IP connection to
>   the host DEVINSPC, port 1433 has failed. Error: "connect timed out.
>   Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL
>   Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the
>   port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a
>   firewall.".)

I am using `jdbc4.2.jar` file. I have set `SQL Server` to use both `SQL Server` and `Windows Authentication`. Hopefully this all makes sense.

If you need anymore info let me know. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: if sql server is running on the same machine, try localhost instead of DEVINSPC

Comment: and also share some pieces of code please

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. This is the code that I am currently trying to use: try{
            
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            String userName = "admin";
            String password = "1234";
            String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=Test";
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
        }
        
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

Comment: I get these errors: run:
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: "connect timed out. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".

Comment: at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:191)
 at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.ConvertConnectExceptionToSQLServerException(SQLServerException.java:242)
 at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SocketFinder.findSocket(IOBuffer.java:2280)
 at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.open(IOBuffer.java:493)
 at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1388)
 at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:1069)

Comment: at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:905)
 at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:452)
 at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1014)
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
 at DeploymentForm.main(DeploymentForm.java:225)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 18 seconds)

Comment: Anyone else have any ideas?